PHP Custom MVC pass multiple parameters
I'm creating a simple MVC framework for a new version of my website I'm working on. Currently I have simple routing, such as /about-us etc ...
Due to my lack of PHP programming experience, I am finding it hard to understand how I can pass multiple parameters in URL.
Below are the url proper working goes from view to route file and route file to contoller method :
url: http://somedomain.com/login
url: http://somedomain.com/register
I'm trying to pass single or multiple parameters in a url that looks like this...
url: http://yoursite.com/product/5/3
url: http://yoursite.com/product_edit/35
url: http://yoursite.com/edit/35/foo
My route file as follows (ruote.php) :
<?php
use App\Services\Route;
use App\Middleware\{
    Auth,
    Guest
};

Route::get('register','RegisterController','index',[Guest::class]);
Route::post('submit-register','RegisterController','register',[Guest::class]);

Route::get('product/{id}/{secondid}','RegisterController','editProduct',[Auth::class]);
Route::get('product_edit/{id}','RegisterController','editProduct',[Auth::class]);
Route::get('product_edit/{id}/{p_name}','RegisterController','editProduct',[Auth::class])



Below are main routing.php file from where generate route for mvc
<?php
namespace App\Services;

class Route{
    private static $routes = [];
    private static $controllerNamespace = 'App\Controllers\\';

    public static function add($uri, $controller,$action, $method='GET',$middleware=[])
    {
        self::$routes[] = [
            'method'=> $method,
            'uri'=> $uri,
            'controller'=> $controller,
            'action'=> $action,
            'middleware' => $middleware
        ];
    }

    public static function get($uri, $controller,$action,$middleware=[]){
        self::add($uri,$controller,$action,'GET',$middleware);
    }

    public static function post($uri, $controller,$action,$middleware=[]){
        self::add($uri,$controller,$action,'POST',$middleware);
    }

    

    public static function handle(){
        $requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $requestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        
        foreach(self::$routes as $route){
    
            // $pattern = '#^' . preg_replace('/{([^\/]+)}/', '(?P<$1>\d+)', $route['uri']) .     '$#siD';
            // if (  preg_match($pattern , $currentUri, $matches)) {}

            if('/'.$route['uri'] === $requestURI && $route['method'] == $requestMethod){

                // handle middleware 
                foreach($route['middleware'] as $middleware){
                    $middlewareClass = new $middleware;
                    $middlewareClass->handle();
                }


                $controllerClass = self::$controllerNamespace.$route['controller'];
                $action = $route['action'];

                $controller = new $controllerClass();
                $controller->$action();
                return;
            }
        }
        echo '404 - page not found';
    }



}

How to add regular expreession in main route file condition. how to replace {id} with browser/href id not getting and that id pass in method class
Below are the coding : https://github.com/PrafulRambade/CustomMvc/tree/master
Now i have issue how to Use GET method with parameters and that parameters should be get in Controller method.I would really like to know how this is done. Thanks a lot!

you have to extract the parameter names from the route uri, extract the values on the actual requestUri then merge it into an assoc array.

You asked something very similar to this yesterday and two people made five comments, none of which you responded to, and then you deleted the question an hour ago.

@ChrisHaas right. I was thinking yesterday I am not actually properly explain questions. So again reframe that. Request you to please help in this

@VanHudsonGalvoso how to do that. Actually I am not getting that part .

What are you need it similar with this.
it's complex procedure.  I could explain a little. This function has 2 arguments 1) path (uri)   2) all routes  loop matching each route by use complied data from route. You can use different procedure no need to stick with one idea.
